# React dialog box will not close on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobile, responsive-design

I have a site(a react app) deployed on gitHub pages. There are cards and when you click on one it should open a modal/dialogue box. Once open clicking on the modal should close it. On the computer the site works fine regardless of the screen dimensions I view it in. However, when viewing the site on a mobile device upon navigating to the page the modals are already open and you cannot close them.

Here is a condensed version of the code I am using.

```
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

    function handleOpen(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        setStatus(true);
    }

    function handleClose(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        setStatus(false);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className='card' onClick={handleOpen}>
                <div className='content'>
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <dialog onClick={handleClose} open={status}>
                <div className='content'>
                    <div onClick={handleClose} className='closeBtn'>x</div>
                    <div className='header'>
                    ...
                    </div>
                    <div className='body'>
                    ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </>
    );
```

It used to be all controlled by a single "handleClick" function that would toggle the status state, but in an attempt to fix this problem I separated it into individual open and close functions. There was no change in the problem.

I also added a designated close button to the modal and while you can see the click registering when you tap it the modal remains open.

It may be worth noting that while the modal is open scrolling on the page should be disabled, but while on mobile you can scroll and see the page moving behind the modal. I am not sure if that is related or a separate problem, but figured it couldn't hurt to bring up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<dialog>` used in this example is a native html element. The way the visibility is handled is through css.

if the open attribute is given to the element a css selector built in in some browsers is applied to show the dialog

[image]

**Note the "user agent stylesheet" next to "dialog[open]" which indicates that this css rule is built in with this browser used.**

If you remove the `open` attribute the "dialog" css rule will be applied (normal css behavior)

[image]

So it will depend on whether these css rules : "dialog" and "dialog[open]" are defined by default in the browser you are using.

So to fix this, manually add the css rules to your webpage.

`

```
dialog {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    inset-inline-start: 0px;
    inset-inline-end: 0px;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color: canvas;
    color: canvastext;
    margin: auto;
    border-width: initial;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 1em;
}

dialog[open] {
    display: block;
}
```

`

Occasionally after testing, you can only add the "dialog[open]" css rule to your stylesheet to not override the "dialog" css rule that comes with the browser by default.

Comment: Well dialog, is not an MUI component. Pretty sure it is a native HTML element, I didn't import it anyway.
However, your solution still served to work around the problem.
Although, you need to keep the open attribute in the dialog element while also rendering it conditionally. Otherwise even when status is true and it is being rendered it will display nothing without the open attribute.

Comment: Yes. It is still true what is mentioned in the answer, seems the `open` prop is what shows/hides the component when it is initially rendered. So when you render it conditionally it is using again the `open` prop so you can set always to `true`. If this answer fixed the problem consider marking it as an answer by ticking the answer check next to it

Comment: If the open attribute only determined visibility on initial render then the dialog boxes would not be visible when you navigate to the page on a mobile device which is part of the problem.
Also if that were true then the attribute couldn't be used to toggle the visibility of the dialog box on any device not just mobile.
Conditionally rendering the dialog box(or any other element) is an alternative way to get the effect I am looking for, but it doesn't solve the problem and make the dialog box useable. If there is not a better answer in a few days I will accept yours, but I will wait for now.

Comment: Edited the answer. The problem is browser specific. Seems the browser used by the mobile devices doesn't come with the required styling needed by the dialog box to function properly. So you can take these needed styles from a working environment and add them manually in your css stylesheet so they will always be available